# Dell Inspirion 13 ( 7368 ) tablet mode

Tags: 16.04, dell, lenovo, tablet

I want the simple functionality of going into tablet mode when the laptop lid is rotated 180 degrees or more. And also achieve automatic screen rotation

Alright, so after searching for a day and going through a lot of online forums I finally found this to be the most useful solution yet -

[Magic Rotation](https://launchpad.net/magick-rotation)  ( using unstable branch to get anything functional in 16.04 )

But even this, is an abandoned project.
Witch some minor changes in the code I could get the screen rotation working ( auto rotate / accelerometer still not working tough )

But the part that I am not able to get to work is detecting the acpi events or hex codes for the lid position change i.e It does not enter tablet mode or normal mode on its own. There is a module provided in the project which has modified dell-wmi but thats also is for some old or different dell laptops with different bios. So now I am not able to get the hex codes that should be put in this wmi file and the  compile it.

Is there any other way to do this? or any solution to the wmi hex codes issue?

Lenovo laptops seem to have a good support for latest ubuntu versions ( ironically ..lol ) but dell inspirion doesn't seem to have any help

Comment: Please [edit] this question to replace `Witch` with `With` so that English translators can parse this page properly.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own drivers/kernel. There isn't proper accelerometer or 2-in-1 support on Ubuntu, yet. Unity 8 is supposed to bring all those new features.

Touch works pretty well though.

On my Pavilion x360, the accelerator doesn't work properly, and only the keyboard is disabled on flip.

See this thread to enable an onscreen keyboard/rotate on flip:

[Switch into tablet mode (in Gnome)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716501/switch-into-tablet-mode-in-gnome)
Oh, btw, its in Gnome.

--upvote if this helped :)--