# Tablet mode for Hp x360 Laptops

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-touch, software-recommendation, tablet, touchscreen

Hp x360 Laptops have a hinge screen that can turn 360 degrees to become like a tablet.

In windows when you turn the screen it detects it and enters "Tablet Mode".

Basically:

- Screen rotates
- Keyboard and touch-pad are disabled
- therefore it shows on-screen keyboard whenever input is required

...at least those are what I care about. I'm looking for software that can do this.

I tried [Magick Rotation](https://launchpad.net/magick-rotation) but no results at all sadly. Any ideas?

*Preferably I need some "ready-to-install" software. (In contrast with long scripts and configuration). I've already spent a whole day running after Magick Rotation. I'm sad :'(*

Answer (score 1):

I have an HP Pavilion 13 x360 and I have the same issues as you have. Currently, there is no official 'tablet mode' support nor is there even proper touch UI support in Ubuntu/Unity. **Unity 8 is supposed to bring those features.**

Until then, stick with Chrome and maybe check out this thread:
[Switch into tablet mode (in Gnome)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716501/switch-into-tablet-mode-in-gnome)

(albeit in gnome)