# How to bring up onboard only when physical keyboard is disabled

Tags: keyboard, tablet, onboard

I have a HP Pavillion x360, running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10. When the laptop is turned into tablet mode, the physical keyboard is disabled as it should be; indicating that ubuntu knows when it is in tablet mode. However, I need to then start onboard and set it to show. Is it possible to get onboard to show automatically when in tablet mode and only when a text input is in focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not at the moment. Unity 8 is supposed to bring those features.

There are an assortment of scripts available on GitHub and the like for rotating the screen and disabling the touchpad, but those still require a shortcut.

And regarding `onboard`, you can call that from the statusbar.

Comment: Rotating of the screen already works without any scripts. Since I'm running GNOME instead of Unity, do you know of anything in the works to do this without having to install Unity?

Comment: @Briggy Not to my knowledge. I expect development to pick up for 2-in-1s (I have the same device as you) especially as more people purchase them, but Unity 8 and Convergence is the closest that I've found to Ubuntu becoming tablet friendly. I've ditched Unity altogether for i3 since Unity with a 2-in-1 is unpolished and unproductive. Check out [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/716501/switch-into-tablet-mode-in-gnome) for more info. If my answer helped please mark it as correct :)